# Appending list in lisp

Tags: list, recursion, append, lisp

In lisp, I am appending lists as:
(setq newlist (append (side a b)(this a b) (that a b) ))

This appends all the required list as: (1 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 6 0)
but what I want is something like this: ((1 0)(0 0)(2 0)(4 0)(6 0))

What should I do to get the required format. Please post code examples in lisp.

Comment: what are `side`, `this`, `that`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's append you are looking for. Perhaps `(list '(side a b) '(this a b) '(that a b)))`?

Comment: @sds side, this and that are other three functions that have lists in them. Like side contains: (1 0 0 0), this contains: (0 0 2 0) and that contains: (4 0 6 0). When I append them I am getting (1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 6 0) but what I need is ((1 0) (0 0) (0 0 ) (2 0) (4 0) (6 0))

Comment: @Sylwester (list '(side a b) '(this a b) '(that a b)) gives collection of same elements inside list and  (list (side a b) (this a b) (that a b)) gives something like this: ((1 0) (0 0 0 3) (0 0 4 0)) but what I need is ((1 0) (0 0) ( 0 3) (0 0 ) (4 0) ).

Comment: functions don't "contain" lists. they may _return_ them. Please edit your question to include the additional information we requested in comments.

Answer (score 1):

So in fact you just need to restructure the elements after you have appended it:

```
(loop :for (e1 e2) 
      :on '(1 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 6 0) 
      :by #'cddr 
      :collect (list e1 e2))

; ==> ((1 0) (0 0) (2 0) (4 0) (6 0))
```

Suggested reading is [LOOP for black belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html), the section you should pay attention to which I've used here is "Looping Over Collections and Packages" and "Destructuring Variables". This is probably the chapter from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)  I read the most. The whole book is very good so every lisper should know about it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. :)